# Singing part of kidush with the leader

Tags: halacha, song-poetry, kiddush, motzi-yedei-chovato, sources-mekorot

Some people, although listening to another's *kidush* (Friday night), sing part of it along with him: specifically (in my experience), the lines starting "*ki vanu vacharta*" when recited with [this tune](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r41BCIkyGsc#t=60s). This *seems* to me arguably not to be a problem (see e.g. [*Mishna B'rura* 690 *s'if katan* 13–14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=310); but see the comments on this question). But I'm wondering whether there are any sources that discuss the issue.

As always, for practical *halacha*, consult your rabbi.

Comment: I do this sometimes but am careful to drop out again before the chatima.  I don't remember where I learned that.

Comment: The megillah case is different because there it's just about your saying the words, whereas by kiddush you need to say it over a cup of wine. What I'm saying is that kiddush is not a pure case of shomea' ke'oneh.

Comment: @DoubleAA, excellent point. I've edited the question.

Comment: I also fail to see what the Mishneh Berura reference has to do with kiddush. (Since by megillah, the reading must be from a kosher megillah, which is the context there). Perhaps you can explain in your question what the concern is?

Comment: @Curiouser, precisely: _MB_ seems to be basing his _tzad l'hachmir_ (in the case that someone reads along with the leader) on the fact that one must read from a scroll: seemingly, then, _kidush_ would be okay.

Comment: @msh210: I just don't see why they two should be compared at all. What is the commonality between them that merits comparison? Megillah seems like a very special case, for a variety of reasons. Kiddush is more like any bracha (I would guess) so that a source in hilchos brachos would be more relevant. I think the MB cite just confuses things.

Comment: @Curiouser, maybe so. In any event, my question stands: whether there are any sources on issue with respect to _kidush_.

Comment: @msh210, I don't have the sefer, but someone once showed me that Ishei Yisrael discusses doing part hearing part saying.

Comment: Related to this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16970

Comment: I'm told there's an article in Techumin 32 which is relevant.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89288

Comment: [similar](/q/102067/170)

Answer (score 3):

To attempt a different parallel, [the Mishnah B'rurah in Siman 124, S"K 16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=294) says that during the repitition of Sh'moneh Esrei, people should not sing along with the Sh'liach Tzibbur because it is *k'yuhara* and like *kalus rosh*.

Comment: szk1210, welcome to the site, and thanks for the reference! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: +1. I wonder, though, whether either of those concerns is relevant here. _Kalus rosh_, in particular, is an issue for _t'fila_ (and a synagogue): does it apply to _kidush_? And as for _yuhara_, well, I wouldn't know where to begin in determining what that concern applies to.

Answer (score 0):

I had always understood that one **should not** speak/sing along with the one reciting kiddush because of the principle of Trei Kali Lo Mishtamai” -- two voices cannot be heard simultaneously (see [Megilla 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.21b?lang=en)).

The Star-K says this as well [here](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/649/the-halachic-guide-to-kiddush/) when listing the conditions to fulfill one's obligation to hear kiddush

> One must hear the entire Kiddush – **One should not speak while
>   listening and should not say “Baruch Hu U’Varuch Sh’mo.”**
>
> If one
>   spoke, b’dieved, the following halachos apply:  **If while speaking one
>   failed to hear a word that is integral to Kiddush (e.g. “Boruch” or
>   “Hashem Elokeinu” after “Boruch Atoh”), one is not yotzai Kiddush.**  If
>   one did not hear a word that is not integral (e.g. “Atoh” or “Kee hu
>   yom”), one need not repeat Kiddush.  [...] One should also not speak between Kiddush and drinking.

Comment: I'm not sure why you boldfaced "If while speaking one failed to hear...". That's clearly not the case here. The one speaking during _kidush_ didn't fail to hear anything, as he heard it by virtue of saying it (unless _t're kale la mishtamae_ applies even of one of them is the hearer's own).

Comment: I understand the "If while speaking one failed to hear" to apply to the person who sings along with the kiddush leader. Therefore he risks failing to hear the kiddush leader as he "speaks over him".

Comment: Worth noting MB 488:8 is not so worried about Trei Kali Lo Mishtamai when it comes to kiddush