# Does partial shome'a ke'one work?

Tags: blessing, motzi-yedei-chovato

There is a *halachic* idea called [*shome'a ke'one*](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2_%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94), that says that (in certain circumstances) one who listens silently to another who says a blessing can fulfil their obligation thereby. Different authorities have different parameters for in what context this is appropriate or what particular intentions/actions need to present in order for this to be effective, but the basic idea exists across the board.

In the cases I've seen discussed (and as is explicit [here](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2501n.htm#11)), the listener must hear the entire blessing out loud from the second person in order to take advantage of *shome'a ke'one*.

Is there any discussion of whether a partial use of *shome'a ke'one* works? That is, if the speaker doesn't say the whole blessing out loud, but the listener says themselves the unheard words, is the listener's obligation fulfilled?

Comment: Tur 281 is interesting in this context

Comment: Cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13385 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16970

Comment: [Riv'vot Efraim 1:71](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&pgnum=61) brings Rabbi Akiva Eiger (I think?) that this works, and some other citations.

Answer (score 1):

Halichos Shlomo on Tefila quotes Reb Shlomo Zalman Auerbach as saying it works. See there 22:11.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a stirah in Tosafots in Berachot, and, the bottom line is that many consider it possible, but Rav Ovadia discourages it (Yechave Da'at 6:28)

Comment: Berachot is large and Tosafot comment many times — can you be more specific? Thank you for pointing me to Yechave Da'at — can you extract a few more details from there for this answer?